# After doing an equation, PHP won't echo the answer

Tags: php

I was just experimenting with PHP trying to get it to find how many bytes are being used in a directory, and convert it to Megabytes. The "totalSpace variable will echo the ammount of bytes, but When I try to echo "newValue" after having it do an equation it just gives the or die message. It is probably something simple, but I am very inexperienced with PHP or any other server-sided or programing languages.

```
<?php
$totalSpace = disk_total_space("./") or die("Error DFS");
echo $totalSpace;

if ($totalSpace > 1048576) {
$totalSpace / 1048576 == $newValue;
}

echo $newValue or die("Error");
?>
```

I tried looking on Stack Overflow and other sources for answers to this question, but couldn't really find anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `$totalSpace / 1048576 == $newValue;` supposed to do?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `$newValue`? Why are you comparing it with `$totalSpace / 1048576`?

Comment: The return value of `echo` is always `undefined`, so the `or die` will always be executed after it echoes.

Comment: This is one of the most basic bits of syntax in all programming languages. You need to go back and read tutorials, SO is not a substitute for learning the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` tests whether two values are equal, it doesn't make them equal. To make a variable equal to an expression, use an assignment.

```
$newValue = $totalSpace / 1048576;
```

Also, `echo` returns `undefined` regardless of what it's printing, so it makes no sense to put `or die("Error")` after it. It can never fail, so it doesn't return a value that indicates success or failure. Just do:

```
echo $newValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar has pointed out, you are never assigning `$newValue` to anything so it is undefined.  The reason it is undefined is because this line doesn't assign anything

```
$totalSpace / 1048576 == $newValue;
```

it is an evaluation statement where using `==` means:

does the `$totalSpace` divided by `1048576` equal `$newValue`

What you want to do is assign the variable `$newValue` using `=` like this

```
$newValue = $totalSpace / 1048576;
```

To add to this answer so as to help you figure these out yourself, I would turn on error reporting to help see errors, warnings and notices, as you develop and learn. They are turned off usually by default in php.ini and can help give you more insight into why things may not be working.  You can add these two lines at the top of your file to override them per script execution.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or Inside your **php.ini** set

```
display_errors = on
```

Had you had that on you would of seen something along these lines

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: newValue -- at line 6
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: newValue -- at line 9
```

complaining about that variable being accessed but never defined.

Comment: This is a great tip, but in the end it doesn't _answer_ the question. I know you're unable to comment on questions because of your reputation, but _always_ make sure your answer actually answers the question. Otherwise it will get marked as _"Not an answer"_

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I would of commented as you had said but I can't quite yet.  I'll refrain from adding extra help as answers, that do not directly answer the question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't answer. Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50421018/edit) this answer and make sure it _answers_ the question. Even if it's the same as Barmar already said, it's perfectly fine as you're giving some extra info.